# MailBee Outlook MsgConvert not saving pictures when convert from .msg to .eml

Tags: .net, email

I'm using C# with .NET framework 4 and MailBee.NET Outlook component.

I use the MsgConvert object's MsgToMailMessage() method to  convert an outlook .msg (i used outlook 2010) file to a MailMessage object. I then called the SaveMessage() method of this object to save the mail in EML format on my computer.

When i open the .eml file, all is fine BUT there are no pictures in the email! In place of the pictures i see "the linked image cannot be displayed. the file may have been removed, renamed, or deleted" messages. The original .msg file did have pictures.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok did more research on this and found out that the version of the MailBee.NET dll I was using (6.9.2.293) did not load any images as attachments.

I contacted the MailBee.Net guys and they sent me their latest dll version (6.9.2.305) and that worked perfectly!